# How to get the execution result from SQL Server stored procedure using Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I need to get the result of stored procedure execution assuming that I'm using exactly this interface: org.hibernate.SQLQuery.

Currently the code looks like that:

```
SQLQuery query = s.createSQLQuery("exec myProc :list, :out);                                
query.setString("list", list);
query.setInteger("out", out);
try {
    query.executeUpdate();
} catch (HibernateException e) { ... }
```

If I'll change it to this: - will it work?

```
 SQLQuery query = s.createSQLQuery("DECLARE @totalRes INT ; exec myProc
 :list, @myInnerParam=@totalRes OUTPUT; select @totalRes");

 query.setString("list", list);query.setInteger("out", out); try {
     Object result = query.uniqueResult(); } catch (HibernateException e) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a stored procedure from Hibernate.

I haven't used all the techniques suggested here, but I usually use the NamedQuery Approach

**Stored procedure:** (this will change depending on the underlying database)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CL_ServiceHoursImport]
    @orderId int = 0  
AS
   select Id, Name from OrderProducts where OrderId = @orderId;
```

**Defining Named Query :** (there are different ways you can define it)

```
<sql-query name="myProcNamedQuery">
<return alias="output" class="com.stackoverflow.StoredProcedureOutput"/>
<![CDATA[exec GetStocks :orderId]]>
</sql-query>
```

**Output class**

```
public class StoredProcedureOutput{
     private int Id;
     private String Name;

     @Override 
      public String toString(){
         return Id + " " + Name + "\n";
      }

    //  getter setters
}
```

**Calling the NamedQuery :** (taken from the example in the blog post)

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("myProcNamedQuery")
    .setParameter("orderId", orderId);

for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    StoredProcedureOutput output = (StoredProcedureOutput)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

**Updates**

Using NamedQuery is just a personal choice.

I would suggest the method which best suits the project you are working on.

Comment: what are the preferences of using the named queries?

Comment: btw, how do you then get the results from the Query object?? which method of query you use? list, iterate, uniqueResult?

Comment: I updated the answer with what you wanted. Let me know if that helps